# Xcode/Mac: keyboard shortcut to type the "OR" sign "||" (double vertical bar)?

Tags: xcode, macos, keyboard-shortcuts

Each time I have to copy paste "||" from elsewhere when I want to type the double vertical bar of the OR sign.

Is there a keyboard shortcut to type it?

Comment: Shift-\ Shift-\ doesn't work?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[This site](http://infopython.wordpress.com/2007/08/28/mac-keyboard-shortcuts-how-write-a-pipe-or-backslash-on-macbook/) lists the shortcut as <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> if you use a Mac keyboard. But the "pipe" symbol does actually exist on the Mac UK keyboard so can't you just press that key twice?

Comment: On the French Mac keyboard there is no pipe key... and brackets/braces are not even printed on the paren keys... see https://support.apple.com/library/content/dam/edam/applecare/images/en_US/keyboards/french_notebook.png

Comment: @neural5torm Have you tried combinations from https://superuser.com/a/416474/287444 or https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/17915? I do not have a Mac in front of me so I cannot check

Comment: Oh but your solution does work though, I was merely trying to explain why the OP asked the question in the first place since his profile seems to indicate he is from France (as I am)...

Answer (score 22):

That did not work for me either. But this one did:

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+ <kbd>7</kbd>   with the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key on the right side of the keyboard or
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd>  with the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key on the left side

Answer (score 14):

I have a Macbook with Danish keyboard, and for me I use the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>, to make the | operand.

Comment: On a never macbook that will be the `option`+`i` combo instead

Answer (score 4):

On Swedish keyboard this worked for me: <kbd>Opt</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

It is Shift + Alt + "I" for Turkish QWERTY users. Shift + Alt + "L" did not work for me, even with U.S. input source.

Answer (score 3):

In my keyboard works with: <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

I am using a UK external keyboard and I had to use <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>~</kbd>.

The <kbd>~</kbd> key is next to carriage return and also has the <kbd>#</kbd> symbol

Answer (score 1):

For macs with German keyboards, press:

<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

for TURKISH QWERTY MBP 16" 2019

option + <

Answer (score 1):

2021 MacBook Pro 14"
UK keyboard

|| --> shift + backslash

below you can find a graphic representation ;)

[image: 2021 MacBook pro uk keyboard OR operator]

Answer (score 0):

Use <kbd>right alt</kbd> + <kbd>(</kbd>. The key is to the right of the <kbd>?</kbd> key on my keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

OnMac keyboard type:
<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> to get | sign

Answer (score 0):

None of this worked for me, my solution was <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd><</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

in my m1 2022 pro `option(alt)` + `-`

Comment: I think it would be helpful to know which keyboard layout you are using (US, German, etc). P.S. I did not downvote this.

Comment: It is the correct solution for Turkish QWERTY.

Comment: Haha. Yes, I got negative votes but that's okay Daniel
Yunus may also be right because I bought the Mac from Turkey